# How to test streaming bandwidth on localhost with Flash Media Server?

Tags: flash, media, bandwidth-throttling

I'm trying to debbug my actionscript (AS3) code on Client side that works with Flash Media Server 4 on localhost. Everything seems fine up to that point.

However, when I'm trying to test my player with other remote streaming servers, I notice bugs because of lower bandwith transmission between the server and the player.

Is there a simple way to simulate lower bandwith with FMS4 on localhost ?

- by config, application.xml, etc.?
- by programmation (main.asc) ?
- both ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to think a little outside of the box, you could use an application such as [NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/). Just make a filter for the specific application and you can throttle the bandwidth to whatever speed you'd like (down to bytes).

**EDIT**

Also, with some brief googling, I was able to find [client.setBandwidthLimit](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashMediaServer/3.5_SS_ASD/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a11afc95e-7ec3.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a11afc95e-7fc1) and [BandwidthCap](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashMediaServer/3.5_AdminGuide/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d119f2926bcf-7ff0.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d119f2926bcf-7f22) in the Application.xml file.

There's also an article on [Configuring Limiting Bandwidth](http://nhippe.com/2010/06/11/flash-media-server-configuration-limiting-bandwidth/) (if that helps).

Comment: Thank you. I tried NetLimiter 4 hours ago, but after using the software, i didn't have succeed with my tests. Maybe I use badly the software, or the version that I use don't support RMTP.  i will try again tommorow.

Answer (score 0):

In accordance with this article "Configuring Limiting Bandwidth" (see link above - thank  Brad Christie) i choose to go with Server-Side ActionScript (SSAS) way. More simple, i think.

Well, here the step what i did :

1. Make a file "main.asc" et copy & paste the code below.

   more info : http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31217

   main.asc

   ```
   var bandwidth;
   application.allowDebug = true;

   // Application callback functions

   application.onConnect = function(client, user) {

       //12800 = 100 Kbps  
       //64000 = 500 Kbps
       //131072 = 1Mbps
       //327680 = 2.5 Mbps
       //983040 = 7.5 Mbps
       //1966080 = 15 Mbps 
       //3932160 = 30 Mbps 
       //6553600 = 50 Mbps 
       //15728640 = 120 Mbps

       bandwidth = 64000;

       client.setBandwidthLimit(bandwidth, bandwidth); 

       trace("clientToServer = " + client.getBandwidthLimit(0) +  " serverToClient="+  client.getBandwidthLimit(1));

       application.acceptConnection(client);

       trace("17 janvier TEST");
   }
   ```
2. Save the file under the folder underneath FMS's applications directory

   Example : FMS\application\dyn
3. Start the FMS server. If there is a problem, check the log file

   Example : FMS\logs_defaultVHost_\dyn_definst_\application.00.log
4. (optional) Change the value ofthe variable bandwidth for your test. I put in comment some common internet connection speed converted in bytes.